# This video is unavailable error in android studio

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am developing an android app to display youtube video and I used Youtube embed video Api in my project.I can embed some vidoes in my app.But some other videos,i got error like "this video is unavailable" error in my project.Plz help me solve this problem sirs.Here is my code

```
package com.example.androidy.ui.main;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.androidy.R;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class Frag2activity1 extends YouTubeBaseActivity {


    private final String API_KEY="AIzaSyBjjOpnJh_D47mLYfU5STATUpZ_4dUCzy0";
    private final String VIDEO_CODE= "nRUvr0KPJDA";
    YouTubePlayerView player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_frag2activity1);

        player = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubePlay);
        player.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                if(!b)
                {
                    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(VIDEO_CODE);
                    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to you stackoveflow,
can you please post your code as well here,
so that will help us to find out the exact error.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow please read [how-to-ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And did you checked that url manually ? Sometimes the videos may be deleted by youtube itself

Comment: Maybe the Videos  URL you are using is not available.

Comment: @KrishnaSony Do you know some way to embed that kind of videos.I need that vidoes really bad for my project .So do you know some kind of trick to embed that kind of videos in android :(

Comment: Add your code here as well. So, it's easy to find out what are you doing wrong

Comment: And i realized that video code like "nRUvr0KPJDA" can embed in my app.But long video code like "OJgHNqX2SQE&list=PLT-ASSlYlFwllBaKTBny8dl5Gn1sLqMjI&index=2&t=3s" can't embed in my app.

Comment: I mean to say add your YouTube Api code in your question not in comment

Comment: @KrishnaSony Ok sorry i will.

Comment: Just get the unique code of the video in that URL removing all other parameters

Comment: @PraveenSP thz bro.Thz to your message I cooled down my head and figured out my error.I remove "&list" in video url and that really solved my problem.Thz u so much for all developers there help solving my problem :).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it's Worked for me.....

```
public class VideoActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    String API_KEY={YOUR_API_KEY}; private final String VIDEO_CODE= "nRUvr0KPJDA";
    private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
    String TAG="VideoActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        youTubePlayerView=(YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubeview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
     youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO_CODE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
        if (youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error Intializing Youtube Player", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(API_KEY, this);
        }
    }
    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return youTubePlayerView;
    }
}
```